# Dynamically declaring Variable inside a class in php

Tags: php, oop, foreach, constructor, dynamically-generated

I have trouble dynamically declaring variables inside a class/object in PHP.

I have a class called Column and it receives an associative array of (names => values) of an unknown length.

I need the class variables to have the exact same name as in the array (and their values to match obviously).

Since Variable Variables method is a bit confusing, when you add on top of it the class/object declaration syntax, I feel I lost myself in it a bit.

I tried something like this:

```
function __construct($array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->$key;
            $this->key=$value;          
        }
    }
```

i would usually not do this

```
$this->$key;
```

I thought `$this->key` would fit the syntax,but apparently I was wrong. If someone could help correct me it would very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the {} syntax:

```
function __construct($array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->{$key} = $value;          
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to be careful that your non-mean-to-be-edited variables names are sent as input (if you have any).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$this->$key;
$this->key=$value;
```

It should be

```
$this->$key=$value;
```

#### What's the difference?

The variable property `$this->$key;` as single statement accesses the property with the name in `$key` but does not do anything with it. But it will trigger a notice *Undefined property* if the property has not been declared or dynamically assigned before.

`$this->key` accesses the literal `key` property, that is `public $key;` if it has been declared explicitly.

`$this->$key` accesses the property with the name stored in `$key`. So if `$key === 'foo'` it is the same as `$this->foo`.

Assigning properties dynamically that have not been declared before is independent of using variable properties. So if the property `$foo` does not exist, `$this->foo = 1` is the same as `$this->$key = 1` with `$key === 'foo'`. Both create a public property `$foo` on the current object.

#### Special cases

If `$key` is not a string, it will be casted to string. If it is an object or resource that cannot be casted to string, you will get a *could not be converted to string* error.

If `$key` converts to an empty string, you will get a *Cannot access empty property* error.

If `$key` starts with a number or contains special characters that are usually not allowed in variable names (like `$`), the property will be created anyway. Accessing properties with names like this is always possible if you use `{}` to use arbitrary expressions as property names. Try this:

```
$o = new stdclass;
$o->{'!"§$%'} = 'it works';
echo $o->{'!"§$%'};
```